# How to sort table data by alphabetical in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have TableData array of objects needs to be sorted by alphabetical.

Is this good way for that?

// THIS IS TABLE OF DATA I USING sort() -- is this correct way?

`tableData.sort()`

```
return (
  <Table.Row
    key={index}
    className={tableData.disabled ? 'adjuster-table-disabled-row' : ''}>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '20%' }}>
      {tableData.email || ''}
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '10%' }}>
      {tableData.firstName || ''}
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '10%' }}>
      {tableData.lastName || ''}
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '7%' }}>
      {tableData.dailyAssignments || ''}
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '7%' }}>
      {tableData.weeklyAssignments || ''}
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '7%' }}>
      {tableData.monthlyAssignments || ''}
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '7%' }}>
      {tableData.dailyAverageTime || ''}
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '7%' }}>
      {tableData.weeklyAverageTime || ''}
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '7%' }}>
      {tableData.monthlyAverageTime || ''}
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell style={{ width: '12%', textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <a
        onClick={() => runtime.navTo(`/analytics/${tableData.userId}`)}
        style={tableData.disabled ? disabledLinkStyle : normalLinkStyle}>
        Get more statistic
      </a>
    </Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>
)
```

I cannot test this, that is reason why I am not sure is this correct.

Comment: Why can't you test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this good way for that?
>
> ```
> tableData.sort()
> ```

That is how you [sort an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), but:

1. As it is it won't work correctly because it will compare the objects as strings.
2. If `tableData` is part of your state, you can't sort it directly in place, because that would be modifying state directly (`sort` sorts the array in place, it doesn't make a copy).
3. If the sorted table is part of your state, you need to do it in a `setState` call, not `render`. You haven't shown where you're doing the `sort` call, but I figured it was important to mention.

So for instance, if you receive an event saying to sort by `firstName`:

```
this.setState(({tableData}) => ({
    tableData: tableData.slice().sort((a, b) => a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName))
});
```

That will trigger `render`. The `slice` makes a copy of the array before sorting it. The `sort` callback sorts on `firstName` using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). (You might use [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) instead if the array has a large number of entries.)